# Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature, while it has a signature

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to define types for a module I installed via npm.

This is the [exported module](https://github.com/Loupax/zero-fill/blob/master/index.js). I'd rather not make changes to this file since I'd like to merge back to the original repo without introducing BCs

```
/**
 * Given a number, return a zero-filled string.
 * From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/
 * @param  {number} width
 * @param  {number} number
 * @return {string}
 */
module.exports = function zeroFill (width, number, pad) {
  if (number === undefined) {
    return function (number, pad) {
      return zeroFill(width, number, pad)
    }
  }
  if (pad === undefined) pad = '0'
  width -= number.toString().length
  if (width > 0) return new Array(width + (/\./.test(number) ? 2 : 1)).join(pad) + number
  return number + ''
}
```

This is the definition I wrote for [this file](https://github.com/Loupax/zero-fill/blob/master/index.d.ts)

```
declare module "zero-fill"{
    export default function zeroFill(width:number, num:number, pad?:string|number):string;
    export default function zeroFill(width:number):{(num:number, pad?:string|number):string};
}
```

And here is an example usage:

```
import * as zeroFill from "zero-fill";
zeroFill(2,0);
```

What confuses me is that the compiler both gives me this error:

```
Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'typeof "zero-fill"' has no compatible call signatures.
```

while at the same time it compiles the typescript and I see it running in the browser. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: same issue. Did you fix it?

Comment: Yes, just answered my own question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what [I ended up doing](https://github.com/Loupax/zero-fill)

Definition:

```
declare module "zero-fill" {
    function zeroFill(width:number, num:number, pad?:string|number):string
    function zeroFill(width:number):{(num:number, pad?:string|number):string}
    export  = zeroFill
}
```

Usage:

```
import zeroFill = require("zero-fill")
zeroFill(4, 1) // '0001'
zeroFill(10, 55) // '0000000055'
zeroFill(1, 1) // '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

When you `import * as zeroFill` you're actually naming the module itself zeroFill. To call the function, you'd have to go `zeroFill.zeroFill(2, 0)`, where the first `zeroFill` is the import alias and the second `zeroFill` is the function.

Comment: There must be something really wrong with my compilation process... Doing `console.log(zeroFill)` shows me that it contains the function itself, not a container object. So if I replace `zeroFill()` with `zeroFill.zeroFill()` the compiler stops complaining but my application crashes... Will check again after I wake up...

Comment: Is the definition file something you wrote yourself? It doesn't appear to directly correspond with the implementation. I think you should set the exports to default exports (`export default function zeroFill`) and then import the default export (`import zeroFill from 'zero-fill'`) because the module.exports in the implementation is a function itself, rather than a container object (as you've discovered).

Comment: Yes and the exact same error occurs when I export the function as default. I updated the question accordingly

Comment: Found [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7554) issue on the TS issue tracker. Will give it a go when possible